# How to manage profile of Powershell and make it faster to load?

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda, conda

While executing python file conda said

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
```

So I used `conda init powershell` which made profile for powershell which takes more than 2 seconds every time it load, if there is way to reduce the load time for this profile please help.

> And one more thing, when I am not dealing with python but using
> powershell for executing some command or running file of other
> programming language that time is also load profile that is made by
> conda for example while I am practicing java it always starts with`(base) PS E:\Java>` and
> it always takes more than 2 second.

> The conclusion is I want use profile which is made by conda only when I am dealing with Python and load time should be faster.

And I am completely happy if there is completely different way to use environment made by conda easily in VScode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open powershell and type `$profile` it will give path of current using profile ,go to that place and open .ps1 file and replace the following code with code already present.

```
 if(($pwd.path -eq "PATH OF PYTHON PROJECT" )-or ($pwd.path -eq "PATH OF OTHER PYTHON PROJECT")){
    
        #region conda initialize
        # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
        (& "C:\Anaconda\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
        #endregion
    }
```

This will cause powershell to use profile that is made by `conda init` will only when you are in particular folder (in the script `"PATH OF PYTHON PROJECT"`)

> At least by doing this is will prevent powershell form using the profile where you do not need it.